# How to assert a condition in Java?

Tags: java, junit, assert, assertion, assertj

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am writing a junit test case, where I need to check the size of list and check whether the list contains certain elements. If it does, then make the test case successful, if not, then make it failed.

```
private void thenExpectedListForDuplicate750PrizeBondsIsChecked()
{
  assertTrue(wonPrizeBonds.size() == 1 && wonPrizeBonds.contains(new PrizeBond(1, 750)));
}
```

It is causing Assertion Error, but the boolean statement is perfectly fine and there is no problem in the code logic.

Comment: Did you implement `equals` and `hashCode` in `PrizeBond`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Did you override the ```equals``` and ```hashcode```methods of the class ```PrizeBond```? There is a high probability that you didn't, therefore the ```contains``` will return false

Comment: Split the assertion P&&Q into two separate ones, one for P, one for Q. Then you can easily see which of the two fails. Rewrite the first assertion so that it uses an assertEquals, so that you get to see the actual size of wonPrizeBonds.

Comment: It would be much cleaner to assert the size of the list and assert whether it contains a certain value separately, rather than combining them with `&&`.

Comment: using AssertJ for both condtions: `then(wonPrizeBonds).containsExactly(new PrizeBond(1, 750));`